# INSERT query in PHP Failing (returns blank error)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I'm using the following code in an attempt to insert user-provided values in `<form>` into an sql table.  When the INSERT query is used in PHPMyAdmin, the insertion is successful, but unsuccessful in the following php.  Connection to the database is successful.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$db_name = "my_db";
$trip;
$odom;
$gals;
$ppg;

if (isset($_REQUEST['trip'])){

$trip = $_REQUEST['trip'];
$odom = $_REQUEST['odom'];
$gals = $_REQUEST['gals'];
$ppg = $_REQUEST['ppg'];

} 

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $db_name, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully ";
```

Here, I've tried using double quotes around the query to form a string; I've omitted the quotes as well, to no avail.  Also, in VALUES, I've tried both single-quotations and the omission thereof as well, without success.  The variables are double values, not strings.

```
 $vals = "INSERT INTO `Log` (`Trip`, `Odometer`, `Gallons_Pumped`,    
 `Price_Gallon`) 
 VALUES ('$trip', '$odom', '$gals', '$ppg')";
```

The return value of `$retval` is false, but no error is provided.

```
$retval = mysql_query($vals);

if ($retval) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $vals . "<br>" . $retval->error;
}

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Is my syntax incorrect?  If not, why is the INSERT query unsuccessful?

Comment: Mixing two extensions is problem...

Comment: Example how can u use PDO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781748/data-from-php-form-is-not-posting-to-mysql/34782699#34782699

Comment: There's also a problem with `mysqli_connect` and the subsequent test for a valid connection. If the connection fails, `$conn` won't be a mysqli connection object, and won't have a `connect_error` method function/method. Following the **`$conn = mysqli_connect(`** (as shown in your code), you'd need to test **`if(!$conn){`**.

Comment: Try echo $vals; and see whether the query is correct..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing `mysqli_*` functions with `mysql_*` functions. You can't do that; they aren't the same library.

Use only `mysqli_*`. Please [don't use `mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

The last block of your code should be (untested):

```
$retval = mysqli_query($vals); // changed

if ($retval) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $vals . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn); // changed
}

mysqli_close($conn); // changed
```

Note the change from `$retval->error` to `mysqli_error($conn)`. By definition, if you reached that point in your code it was because `$retval` evaluated to `false` and therefore was not an object.

---

Also, please note that you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Your SQL statement is this:

```
$vals = "INSERT INTO `Log` (`Trip`, `Odometer`, `Gallons_Pumped`, `Price_Gallon`)
VALUES ('$trip', '$odom', '$gals', '$ppg')";
```

But those values (`$trip`, etc.) come straight from the user (via `$_REQUEST`). Very bad things can happen if your user submits values containing, for example, the `'` character. You should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), like this:

```
$vals = "INSERT INTO `Log` (`Trip`, `Odometer`, `Gallons_Pumped`, `Price_Gallon`)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $vals)) {
    // adjust "sddd" below to match your data types; see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sddd", $trip, $odom, $gals, $ppg);

    $retval = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $vals . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: This is best answer I suggest u add sql injection instruction chk OP code open for injection. . As mentioned in this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781748/data-from-php-form-is-not-posting-to-mysql/34782699#34782699

Comment: @devpro Good point. I added a discussion of SQL injection. Adrian, please see the second half of the answer for a more secure way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are mixing two incompatible APIs - the deprecated `mysql` functional API and the newer object oriented `mysqli`.

It would be best to convert your code to `mysqli` and it will work.

Comment: Agreed here is the example of PDO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781748/data-from-php-form-is-not-posting-to-mysql/34782699#34782699

Answer (score 1):

There's another problem in your code. You're mixing procedural style and object- oriented style calls. Your test for a valid connection in this code isn't valid:

```
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $db_name, $password);

  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
```

In procedural style, `mysqli_connect` won't return an object if the connection fails. So `$conn` won't have a method/function `connect_error`. You need to test just `$conn`, and then call the procedural style `mysqli_connect_error`.

```
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $db_name, $password);
  if(!conn){
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error);
  }
```

Another alternative fix to change the initial assignment to `$conn` to be object oriented style (i.e. using `new`)

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php